# Why is the Catch(Exception) almost always a bad Idea?

Tags: java, exception

Why is the `catch(Exception)` almost always a bad Idea?

Comment: Good that you put *almost* in. I can not imagine not to do that in global error handling.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114658/catching-base-exception-class-in-net

Comment: What most developers intend to do here is `catch (final RuntimeException e) {...}`, which is perfectly fine for a generic handler of unexpected errors (logging, escape sequences, etc). Anything else matching `Exception` will be a checked exception - each of which you'll be forced to recon with anyway, and each should be carefully considered individually. `InterruptedException` is probably the most common offender that can get unintentionally caught with `Exception` (zap!).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Because when you catch exception **you're supposed to handle it properly**. And you cannot expect to handle all kind of exceptions in your code. Also when you catch all exceptions, you may get an exception that cannot deal with and prevent code that is upper in the stack to handle it properly.

The general principal is to catch the most specific type you can.

Comment: For instance a java.lang.InterruptedException is raised when a thread is asked to stop. If caught and ignored, the thread processing can't be stopped gracefully and your code become improper to run in a worker thread. This is one example, there may be others.

Comment: I'm a big fan of people understanding their frameworks. The primary reason this advice is terrible is, 90% of the time, the code people are writing exception handling for, is at the boundary of their API. I agree that within an API, you should always catch appropriate exceptions, but when you're at an API boundary, please catch everything that doesn't kill the system.

Comment: @coding *You* are not normally writing framework code. *Your framework* will catch `Exception` and take appropriate action.

Comment: Or catch it, log it, and the throw it again

Answer (score 33):

Short story: it's called bug masking. If you have a piece of code which is not working well and throwing exceptions (or you pass malformed input to that piece of code) and you just blind your eyes by catching all possible exceptions, you will actually never uncover the bug and fix it.

Comment: "Catching" an exception does not mean to just continue executing like there's nothing wrong.  A "catch" block is a block of code where you do **something**.  That **something**, might to be to log information about the exception, about what the user was doing or the state of the UI, to close connections and files  so the app ca exit gracefully, and to notify the user what happened.  How is this "masking" anything?

Comment: @user316117 `Exception` is the top class of all exceptions in Java. Catching that means you catch all possible errors. How would you know what to do in such a block? If you want to react to a certain error, catch its specific exception and work with it. There's no practical use to catching all possible exceptions except to blind your eyes (and I've seen plenty of colleagues doing it because they want to go home at the end of the workday).

Comment: @dimitarvp Throwable is top class of all exceptions. It has two subclass which partitions exceptions in two branches. One of them is EXCEPTION and other is ERROR.

Answer (score 10):

You should only catch exceptions if you can properly handle them. As you cannot properly handle all possible exceptions you should not catch them :-)

Comment: A major problem with such thinking is that there are many situations in which the proper handling for 99% of the exceptions that might get thrown would be to report that some action couldn't be completed and get on with life, but identifying every single type of exception for which that would be the proper course of action would be difficult if not impossible.  Too bad there's no mechanism for distinguishing "could not satisfy request" exceptions from "CPU is on fire" exceptions.

Comment: CPU is on fire is probably going to cause some kind of `java.lang.Error`.

Comment: > An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.

Answer (score 8):

I find two acceptable uses of `catch(Exception)`:

- At the top level of the application (just before returning to the user). That way you can provide an adequate message.
- Using it to mask low-level exceptions as business ones.

The first case is self-explanatory, but let me develop the second:

Doing:

```
try {
    // xxxx
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error XXX",e)
}
```

is bug masking like @dimitarvp said.

But the below is different:

```
try {
    // xxxx
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new BusinessException("Error doing operation XXX",e)
}
```

This way you aren't ignoring bugs and hiding them under the carpet. You are providing a high-level exception with a more explanatory message to higher application layers.

It's also always important to manage exceptions at the correct layer. If you escalate a low-level exception to a high business layer, it's practically impossible for the higher layer to manage it well.

In that case, I prefer to mask the low level exceptions with a business one that provides a better context and message and that also has the original exception to be able to go into the details.

Even so, if you can catch more concrete exceptions and provide better treatment for them you must do it.

If in a block of code you can get an `SQLException` and a `NetworkException` you must catch them and provide adequate messages and treatment for each of them.
But if at the end of the try/catch block you have an `Exception` mapping it to a `BusinessException` it's ok for me.

In fact, I find it adequate when higher service layers only throw business exceptions (with details inside).

Comment: - At the top level of the application is enough to catch RuntimeException.
- to mask low-level exceptions should be at least listed catched exceptions. What if is some time later introduced new catched exception, which should be handled differently? How will you find in your code, where to change the code?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you need. If you need to handle different types of exceptions in different ways then you should use multiple catch blocks and catch as much specific exceptions as you can.

But sometimes you may need to handle all exceptions in the same way. In such cases catch(Exception) may be ok. For example:

```
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogError(e);
        ShowErrorMessage(e); // Show "unexpected error ocurred" error message for user.
    }
```

Comment: That's not a good pattern to follow; logging should not be done like this because you'll get a bunch of the same entries for each "level" of try-catch.

Comment: I agree, I used it only as example. May be not the best example :)

Comment: @Lucero: I would think it better to have a logging framework that can consolidate redundant entries, than assume that whatever layer handles (swallow) an exception will log it.  Further, unless exceptions are so numerous that logging them multiple times would pose a performance bottleneck (in which case I'd say *that's* a problem that needs fixing) I would think having redundant information in the log, which could then be filtered by a log viewing utility, would be preferable to having a more concise log which lacks the one piece of information one ends up needing.

Comment: You should always list catched exceptions. They are predicted. If you want to catch unpredicted exceptions and handle them the same way, you should catch RuntimeException instead.

Answer (score 5):

Because you don't really know why an exception happened, and several exceptions require very special car to be handled correctly (if possible at all), such as a OutOfMemoryException and similar low-level system exceptions.

Therefore, you should only catch exceptions:

- which you know exactly how to deal with it (e.g. FileNotFoundException or so)
- when you will re-raise them afterwards (for instance to perform post-fail cleanup)
- when you need to transport the exception to another thread

Comment: OK, nitpicking on a 10 year old answer here: In Java, `OutOfMemoryError` is a `Throwable` but of the subtype `java.lang.Error`. So it is not an `Exception` and would not actually be caught by the clause in the question.
That said, there are also `Exceptions` that should (almost) never be caught, like `NullPointerException`, which indicate a programming error and your points are all valid.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what yet answered by @anthares:

> Because when you catch exception **you're supposed to handle it properly**. And you cannot expect to handle all kind of exceptions in your code. Also when you catch all exceptions, you may get an exception that cannot deal with and prevent code that is upper in the stack to handle it properly.
>
> The general principal is to catch the most specific type you can.

`catch(Exception)` is a bad practice because it catches all RuntimeException (unchecked exception) too.

Answer (score 0):

This may be java specific:

Sometimes you will need to call methods that throw checked exceptions. If this is in your EJB / business logic layer you have 2 choices - catch them or re-throw them.

Catching specific exception classes means you will need to re-analyze your actions for which exceptions can be thrown when you look to see how this code handles exceptions. You will often get into a "what if..." situation and it can be a lot of effort just working out if exceptions are handled correctly.

Re-throwing means that code calling your EJBs will be littered with catching code that will typically not mean anything to the calling class. n.b. throwing checked exceptions from EJB methods will mean that you are responsible for manually rolling back any transactions.

Comment: Not totally true. In EJBs, catched exceptions are treated as application exception by default. But you can redefine them as a system exception as well.

Answer (score 0):

But sometimes it is OK! Like if you have a piece of code that does something 'extra', which you really don't care about, and you don't want it to blow up your application. For example, I worked on a large application recently where our business partners wanted a certain daily transaction to be summarized in a new log file. They explained that the log wasn't all that important to them, and that it did not qualify as a requirement. It was just something extra that would help them make sense of the data being processed. They did not need it, because they could get the information elsewhere. So that is a rare case where it is perfectly fine to catch and swallow exceptions.

I also worked at a company where all Throwables were caught, and then rethrown inside a custom RuntimeException. I would not recommend this approach, but just pointing out that it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it another valid scenario to ensure that a thread keeps alive catching exception inside it?

```
Thread shouldRunWhenApplicationRuns = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // do something that should never end
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log it
        }
    };
    shouldRunWhenApplicationRuns.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sonar has also a good Explanation, why this is not a good idea, and how it can be prevented:

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2221

> Catching Exception seems like an efficient way to handle multiple possible exceptions. Unfortunately, it traps all exception types, both checked and runtime exceptions, thereby casting too broad a net. Indeed, was it really the intention of developers to also catch runtime exceptions? To prevent any misunderstanding, if both checked and runtime exceptions are really expected to be caught, they should be explicitly listed in the catch clause.