# Sqlite, How to check if a row contains either string

Tags: android, string, sqlite, row

Using the code below i can check if a row contains a single string ( String a) but how would i check if a row equals either string (String a or b)?

```
public Cursor fetchMyList() {
        String[] columns = { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_SUMMARY,
                KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_EMAIL };
        String selection = "description=?";
        String a = "blue";
                String b = "red";

        String[] selectionArgs = { a };
               // String[] selectionArgs = { a , b}; ///tried this dont work!!
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();
        if (numberOfRows <= 0) {
            return cursor;
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only pass 2 arguments if you declare 2 arguments. This is what you want:

```
String selection = "description=? OR description=?"; // Select rows with either description
String[] selectionArgs = {a , b};
```

I strongly suggest you check [SQL language](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

PS: do not catch `Exception`. You'll regret it later. Catch specifc Exception children; in your case you want to catch `SQLException`.

PS2: use `Log` instead of `printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Thank you so much I've spent hours searching for this answer, is there a reason I shouldn't be using Exception?

Comment: You're welcome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea