# Can I use uncaughtexceptionhandler to move to next block of codes?

Tags: android, uncaughtexceptionhandler

Can I use uncaughtexceptionhandler to ignore the exception and move forward?
If I can, how to write that handler?

for example:

```
try{
  //something
}catch(exception e){
  //something
}

//AND WHEN SOME UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION APPEAR, IGNORE EXCEPTION AND MOVE TO NEXT STEP

try{
  //something else
}catch(exception e){
  //something else
}
```

thank you for your attention

Comment: Since you are catching Exception, then every exception would be caught as Exception is direct/Indirect superclass for every exception. Also catching the Exception is not good idea. You should catch only the exception that you thing you will get and handle that exception appropriately. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea]

Comment: "Can I use Uncaughtexceptionhandler to ignore the exception and move forward?" No. Uncaught exceptions means that you have exited all the methods and nothing has handled it. You can't go back in program flow.

Comment: thank you, I post this question because I troubled with uncaughtexception error in logcat even after use "Exception"
I will think the other way because I can't use Uncaughtexceptionhandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `try .. (catch) .. finally` construct to execute code even if an exception was thrown but not handled.

```
try {
    // do things that can throw an exception
} finally {
    // this block is !always! executed. Does not matter whether you
    // "return"ed, an exception was thrown or everything was just fine.
}
```

if you add a `catch` in there then execution order is `try` up to the point where the exception happened, then the first appropriate `catch` block, then the `finally` block.

If you want to execute code in the finally block only if there was *no* exception, set some flag as the last operation of the `try` block.

```
boolean doFinally = true;
try {
    // flag stays "true" if something throws here
    doFinally = false;
} finally {
    if (doFinally) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Note: if you don't `catch` an otherwise uncaught exception somewhere your app will still crash after it has exectued the code in `finally`.