# I used the getHostAddress() with try- catch, but when I run this it just doesnt run What is wrong in this?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
public class MainA extends Activity {
    WifiManager wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info=wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    String ip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);

        try{
            InetAddress ownIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            ip=ownIP.getHostAddress();
            //System.out.println("IP of my Android := "+ownIP.getHostAddress());
        }catch (Exception e){
            //System.out.println("Exception caught ="+e.getMessage());
        }

        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                tv1.setText(ip);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It stops with the dialog, should I use other method or any other way of using it.I used the getHostAddress() with try- catch, but when I run this it just doesnt run What is wrong in this?

Comment: Stops with "the dialog"? What does the exception say? We need the troubleshooting information if you want help.

Comment: @user3293724 Would you provide the `stack-trace` of exception.

Comment: The javadoc for `.getLocalHost()` says that it is "[...] achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.". Unavailable/slow name resolution?

Comment: My guess would be NetworkOnMainThreadException. Please log your exception stacktraces and do not just ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to get the host of your loopback address and that's throwing an `Exception`, as it's not being resolved to any host. You're probably catching that `Exception` but as you have not code inside, you think there's nothing happening.

By the way: Catching *all* exceptions is a bad practice as you might be catching some exception that is not intended by the `try` block. You can read more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea).