# Intercept and rethrow a Java unhandled exception

Tags: java, exception

I've coded a method with a catch-all handler, but I need to rethrow the exception as if it were unhandled, so that a caller (much) further up the call stack can handle it. The trivial way to do this is simply:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
   // do something here...
   // and rethrow
   throw ex;
}
```

But the problem is that, because of the `throw` statement, Java requires this method to declare itself as `throws Exception`, which in turn, requires all the callers to handle the exception or declare themselves as `throws Exception`. And so on up the call chain...

Is there any simple way to rethrow the exception as if the current method did not handle it?

Comment: Exactly like this. If you didn't have the try/catch here, your method would need to `throws Exception` (or, at least, `throws` the types of exceptions actually thrown in the method calls in the `try` block).

Comment: `catch(RuntimeException ex)`. Unless your code throws a checked exception, then you will want a handler for `RuntimeException` and another for the the specific checked exceptions - wrap in `RuntimeException` and rethrow.

Comment: "with a catch-all handler" is rarely a good idea. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Just in case: you know about `finally`, right?

Comment: @Raedwald I need this for a scripting engine which itself could throw anything. I need to intercept the exception to add additional information, but then let other libraries handle it.

Comment: @adelphus: Just how inclusive is "anything"? What do the methods inside the `try` declare for `throws`?

Comment: @user2357112 yes - finally would be ideal, but I need access to the exception which I don't think is possible from a finally block

Comment: @user2357112 The exceptions can be thrown by a native component. Hence the catch-all, because there is no declared list of throwable types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Catch(Exception) almost always a bad Idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @adelphus: Well, if you really could be propagating any exception type whatsoever out of there, then you should declare `throws Exception`. The catch-all `catch` has nothing to do with it; you should declare `throws Exception` even if you didn't have the `catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do what @radoh has said and just wrap into a `RuntimeException`, but one downside of this is your stacktrace is now polluted and will show the offending line to be where you declare `throw new RuntimeException(ex)`.

An alternative is to use Lomboks `SneakyThrows` mechanism, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    methodWithException();
}

private static void methodWithException() {
    try {
        throw new Exception("Hello");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Lombok.sneakyThrow(e);
    }
}
```

Your stacktrace will remain intact, but you no longer need to declare `throws Exception`.

It's worth reading the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows.html) on why you should/shouldn't do this

Comment: The sneakyThrow looks like exactly what I want - thanks. And yes, I know it's bad. I feel evil, but my other alternative is to code a jni library which throws without the Java compiler checking it. Not nice.

Answer (score 3):

You have exactly two options with (checked) exceptions:

1. Handle them in the method via a `try`/`catch` (which may include rethrowing as a different exception type)
2. Declare that the method `throws` the exception.

If you want to rethrow the exception as if this method did not catch it, your only option is 2.

Note: you *only* want to `catch (Exception e)` if a method in the `try` block *actually* throws `Exception`. Otherwise, catch the specific exception types.

Comment: I would do 2., but there's a massive call chain dependant on this method which would, in turn, require several hundred methods to all declare themselves as `throws Exception`. Not my idea of fun.

Comment: @adelphus if that's what those method _do_ (i.e. throw an exception), then that's what they **have to** declare they do.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ...unless the method is native. In which case, it doesn't have to declare anything and can throw anything.

Comment: @adelphus my point was more from the API side than Java's requirements. There is in fact to requirement whatsoever for a method to declare that it throws a checked exception or to handle one when it occurs. But I know, from experience, that methods that randomly and without warning blow up make programmers somewhat...unhappy. So I would suggest that you 1) create an `AdelphusException` 2) wrap anything coming from the native method in one and 3) declare that your API throws them.