# Sum of string array elements in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a `String` array which have both integers as well as strings. I want to calculate the sum of all integer array elements.

```
class Array{
String container[] = {"Joe","12","Chandler","15","67","Rajat",'a'};
int sum;
for(String element:container){
    int num = Integer.parseInt(element); 
    sum += num;
}
void print(){
    System.out.print(sum);
}
}
class ArrayDemo{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Array a = new Array();
    a.print();
}
}
```

But the code `int num = Integer.parseInt(element)` gives NumberFormatException because `Joe`,`Chandler`,`Rajat` are not integers. So, how to resolve this problem.
The answer should be the sum of `12+15+67=94`

Thanks in advance

Comment: you sample code has huge amount of error

Comment: Which type of error?

Comment: No, it is not compiling but why because I wrote code directly in the class?

Comment: yes that is a reason. That for loop will give error and also the last element of your array is not a string that is also an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include your parse inside a try catch block

```
for(String element:container){
  try {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(element); 
    sum += num;
  catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
    System.out.println ("Element " + element + " in the array is not an integer");
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to close try block else your code is working and it solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

you need to handle that exception:

```
class Array{
String container = {"Joe","12","Chandler","15","67","Rajat",'a'};
int sum;
for(String element:container){
    try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(element); 
    catch(Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
    sum += num;
}
void print(){
    System.out.print(sum);
}
}
class ArrayDemo{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Array a = new Array();
    a.print();
}
}
```

Use `try-catch` for this. If exception happens, just continue to next iteration in `for` loop. When its a number, it will be added to `sum`.

Another approach is to check each char in string if its a number. This is a quite long code, so use one existing (you will need to include Apache Commons library):

```
NumberUtils.isNumber(String str)
```

or

```
StringUtils.isNumeric(String str)
```

When this gives you true, add it to `sum`.

Comment: This is incredibly bad practice: `catch(Exception e) {
        continue;
    }`

Comment: Why would it be a bad practice?

Comment: more or less [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea)

Comment: As it says, you need to handle all exceptions... This does it...